# How to dynamically add a button to a popup window?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, popupwindow, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to write a function that opens a popup window, and populates it with button links to all of the previous pictures or recorded audio files the app has recorded. I tried to write the function so that it will work for audio files or images. The goal is to have a pop-up window appear on the screen which has a button for each of the previous files and will open the designated file on click. The app will successfully open the popup window, but it will only be populated by the auto-defined button (back) which will close the popup window. However, white space appears underneath the back button, which increases the height of the scroll view and allows for scrolling within the pop-up window but no buttons actually appear.

Initially, my problems came from not including pw.getContentView() (pw is my popupwindow) for each of my layout elements, but I'm not sure what it does exactly so that may be a part of the problem.

This is the function that is called to open the popup window.

```
private void display_media(int check, String header_text){
    //The check variable is a 1 or 0 depending on if it's an image or an audio.
    // header_text is a simply text to replace the default header.
    try{
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) NewPlan_Two.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.files_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.show_media));
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout,width/4,height/3,true);//width and height are predefined values

        Button close_button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.back_scroll);
        close_button.setOnClickListener(close_view);
        TextView header =(TextView) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.previous_files);
        header.setText(header_text);

        LinearLayout l_l = (LinearLayout) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.scroll_linear);
        for(String media_file: files){ // this is defined and explained below
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button new_button = new Button(this);
            if(check==0){
                new_button.setId(image_id_count);
                image_id_count++; // this is initialized to 3000
                button_id = new_button.getId();
            }
            else{
                new_button.setId(audio_id_count);
                audio_id_count++; // this is initialized to 2000
                button_id = new_button.getId();
            }
            new_button.setText(media_file);
            l_l.addView(new_button,params);

            if(check==0)
                button_two= (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(button_id);
            else
                button_two = (Button) pw.getContentView().findViewById(button_id);
            button_two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pw.dismiss(); 
                    // this will be replaced with code to open the image or audio, but I haven't written it yet.
                }   
            });         

        } 
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To parse the audio or image files, I use this function. It is successfully getting the names of the files. It is called with either "mp4" or "png" as the argument.

```
private void parse_Files(String fileType){
    files = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folder = new File(abs_path); // abs_path is the path to the folder with the files
    File[] list_of_files = folder.listFiles();
    for(int count = 0; count < list_of_files.length;count++){   
        String file_name = list_of_files[count].getName();
        String[] parsed_list = file_name.split("\\.");
        if(parsed_list[1].equals(fileType))
            files.add(parsed_list[0]);
    }
}
```

Finally here is the xml file that opens as the popup window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/show_media"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:padding = "15dp"
 android:background="#DCDDF7">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/previous_files"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/previous_files"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scroll_linear">

        <Button 
             android:id="@+id/back_scroll"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/back"
             android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>      

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I tried to change it to a list view, but I am getting the same issue. It opens a pop-up and there are x buttons corresponding to x associated files, but none of the buttons have text or do anything on click. What am I missing?

Here is the revised code:

```
private void display_media(int check, String header_text){
    try{
        display_media_array=new String[files.size()];
        display_media_array=files.toArray(display_media_array);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) NewPlan_Two.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.files_layout, null);
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);

        ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, display_media_array));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                pw.dismiss();                   
            }
        });

        Button close_button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.back_scroll);
        close_button.setOnClickListener(close_view);
        TextView header =(TextView) pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.previous_files);
        header.setText(header_text);

        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the new xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/show_media"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#DCDDF7"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="15dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/previous_files"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/previous_files"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using a `ListView` with one button per cell, rather than wrapping a `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. That way Android takes care of the dynamically generated UI elements, scrolling, recycling, etc. All you need to do is write the adapter and onClickListener.

Comment: Would that solve the issue or just make it cleaner? I'll get on that though, thanks.

Comment: Both, actually. `ListView`s in popups or dialogs are pretty simple, and there are plenty of examples out there. You don't have to worry about sizing the `ScrollView` or `LinearLayout` dynamically, and can go straight to debugging your layout. To be perfectly honest, I haven't read your code, but there's a good chance it'll work once you simplify. That's why I posted as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate it!